# Kohana 'Model not found' in Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, kohana

I've a Kohana 3.3 project working in a linux server and I moved it to Amazon EC2 linux instance.

It loads correctly all 'classes/Model/xxxxx.php' Models, but fails if model has no file definition (models that only resides in database), showing a 'Model not found' error.

Also I've some problems with model's properties, showing a 'The aaaaaa property does not exist in the Model_Bbbbbb class'

I am aware of PSR-0 implementation on Kohana >3.2

Model not found error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_role' not found
```

Property error:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The team property does not exist in the Model_User class
```

These are my implementations:

/application/classes/Model/user.php

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User
{
    public function rules()
        {
        …
        }
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'team' => array('through' => 'user_teams'),
    );
}
```

Database tables:

- roles
- users
- user_teams

Since this code is working on a previous linux server, I discarded PSR-0 problems, and I think this is a misconfiguration of Amazon Linux AMI.

Any idea?

Comment: In Kohana, there are no models that only reside in the database (but such, that are defined in the MODPATH/SYSPATH). Where is the missing model error triggered? It should state `Model_Role` (and not **r**ole)

Answer (score 0):

> Model not found error:
>
> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_role' not found

You need to have a PHP class for each model. It's possible it can be very simple, such as `class Model_Role extends ORM {}`, but it needs to exist and be placed in the right directory for autoloading.

> Property error:
>
> Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The team property does not exist in the
>   Model_User class

probably you need to update the `$_table_columns` property in your `Model_User` to include the `team` field. The other possibility is your database doesn't have the `team` column in the `users` table.